# Template as template argument for specialisation

Tags: c++, templates

Let's say I have a template class

```
template<typename T>
class MyClass{
    //...
}
```

Now i want to declare function:

```
template<typename U, typename M>
void foo(U first, M second){
    //...
}
```

Now I need to write a specjalization of this function which takes MyClass as second template argument. I tried to write something like this

```
template<typename U, typename M>
void foo(U first, template<typename T> MyClass<T> second){
    //...
}
```

Unfortunately it does not work. Do you have any sugestions how to do it?

Answer (score 3):

As simple as

```
template<typename T>
class MyClass{
 // ...
};

template<typename U, typename M>
void foo(U first, M second){
}

template<typename U, typename M>
void foo(U first,  MyClass<M> second){

}
```

Comment: I have defined 
    template<typename T>
    class MyClass{
    // ...
    };

    template<typename U, typename M>
    void foo(U first, M second){
    }

    template<typename U, typename M>
    void foo(U first,  MyClass<M> second){

    }


But for a call like foo<MyClass<int>,MyClass<int>>(obj1,obj2) it calls an unspecialized function where obj1 and obj2 are objects of MyClass<int>

Comment: @Matimath That's because you provided explicit template arguments which don't allow selecting the more specialized function.  Do just `foo(obj1, obj2)` or `foo<MyClass<int>, int>(obj1, obj2)`.